# authentication and authorization in mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm using mvc5 with default authentication and authorization by create individual User Account in visual studio 2013.But i have a problem.
in path "/View/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml" have code follow:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

i'm try create a account for first project and login successful.
after, i create second project and run and i  don't login but second project display login successful. i'm checked Request.IsAuthenticated=true. why i don't login but the second project  display login successful.
Sory, my bad english

Answer (score 1):

i think if you use code and make Session its well be butter:

code :

Session("Admin") = "AdminLoginn"
 Session.Timeout = 120

this code in login page

and you must check code in next page :
        If Session("Admin") <> "AdminLoginn" Then
            Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx", False)
            Exit Sub
        End If

thanx

Comment: yes, thanks. This way is a solution. But why identity is confused.
have any another way?